# Cos'è "la pedana" in uno spettacolo teatrale?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro autobiografico *Un grande avvenire dietro le spalle* di Vittorio Gassman ho letto:

> I nodi al pettine vennero con l'*Oreste*, che io avevo scelto per il mio spettacolo. A Luchino, Alfieri non interessava: mi disse che l'avrebbe fatto ma a modo suo. Il modo suo sortì una rappresentazione sontuosa e barocca, con un'orchestra di ottanta professori che suonava Beethoven sul palcoscenico dietro un velario rosso trasparente, e la scena installata al centro della platea. Intorno alla **pedana** campeggiavano cinque leoni in finta pietra, che avevano un doppio scopo, estetico e funzionale: vi si annicchiavano ogni sera, introducendosi per stretti cunicoli, cinque piccoli suggeritori destinati a Ruggero Ruggieri.

Per "Luchino" Gassman intende Luchino Visconti. Non capisco il senso di "pedana" in questo brano. Ho cercato il vocabolo in alcuni dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente relativo al teatro. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "pedana" in uno spettacolo teatrale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La pedana è una struttura in legno sulla quale si sale in piedi, con il doppio scopo di innalzare rispetto al pubblico e di amplificare la voce o i suoni, grazie ad un effetto di cassa di risonanza.
Spesso le orchestre sono poste su grandi pedane di forma semicircolare. Si chiama pedana anche il podio su cui sale il direttore d'orchestra.
Visto che in questa frase si descrivono cinque leoni che servono a nascondere i suggeritori, si deve pensare a qualcosa di grandi dimensioni, probabilmente si parla della pedana al centro della platea su cui si svolge la scena.